# Backbone Routes with pushState on are not working when you refresh page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a simple router:

```
Erin.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
    },
    routes: {
        '' : 'index',
        'project/:img' :'project',
    },
    index: function() {
        var galleryView = new Erin.GalleryView();
    },
    project: function(img) {
        console.log(img);
    }
});
```

The template for the `Erin.GalleryView` is(thinking there might be an issue there):

```
<script type="text/template" id="gallery-grid">
        <a href="/project/<%= id %>">
            <img src="<%= thumbnail %>" />
            <span class="desc">
                <div class="desc-wrap">
                    <p class="title"><%= title %></p>
                    <p class="client"><%= client %></p>
                </div>
            </span>
        </a>
    </script>
```

The GalleryView and the GalleryItem code.

```
Erin.GalleryItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'project-container',
    //Grab the template html
    template: _.template($('#gallery-grid').html()),
    //Set up the render function
    render: function() {
        //What is the $el in this case?
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

Erin.GalleryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#projects',
    initialize: function() {
        //create new collection
        this.col = new Erin.Gallery();
        //Listen to all events on collection
        //Call Render on it
        this.listenTo(this.col,'all',this.render);
        //Fetch data
        this.col.fetch();
    },
    render: function() {
        //Get reference to the view object
        var that = this;
        //Empty div
        this.$el.empty();
        //For each model in the collection
        _.each(this.col.models, function(model){
            //call the renderItem method
            that.renderItem(model);
        },this);
    },
    renderItem: function(model) {
        //create a new single item view
        var itemView = new Erin.GalleryItem({
            model:model
        });
        //Append items to to element, in this case "#projects"
        this.$el.append(itemView.render().el);  
    }
});
```

Then I have a document ready

```
$(function() {
    var router = new Erin.Router();
    $('#projects').on('click', 'a[href ^="/"]', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        router.navigate($(this).attr('href'),{trigger: true});
    });
});
```

When you load the page and click one of the links in the `#project` section, everything behaves as it should, if you refresh that page however, I get an error that breaks the page.

From the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < js/jquery.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < js/underscore-min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < js/backbone.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < erin.js:1
```

It also states stuff like:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8888/project/js/backbone.js".
```

For all the links and scripts in the head of the document.

Which all seem to point at the first line of the index.html file. So if I click a link, it will console the img id I am looking for from my data, if I refresh the page OR type that link in, I get the errors above. Am I correct in thinking I should be able to save the links `domain.com/project/coolthing` and have that work when someone comes to the page. Have I missed something? Implemented something weird? A nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: could you add the code for GalleryView? At least the portion which loads the template?

Comment: @providencemac Added that in the top there. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Where to exactly add that router parsing thing, I have no idea!

Answer (score 8):

You have a problem server-side. You're probably already half-way to the solution.

It looks like you have correctly configured your server to send your app HTML on *any* hit, except for your assets (js, css) which have precedence.

The problem lies in you main HTML, where your JS files are referenced with a relative path. When you reload after pushState has updated the URL to `/project/1` the base URL becomes `/project/`.

ie. you have

```
<script src="js/backbone.js"></script>
```

when you should have

```
<script src="/js/backbone.js"></script>
```

As a result, when the browser tries to load backbone.js it doesn't find it (/project/js/backbone.js doesn't exist), and hits the server catchall that delivers the app HTML (hence the parsing error that chokes on `<`).

My explaination may not be crystal clear, it's pretty late over here, but I'm sure you'll understand !

Comment: So simple, but this is it. Thanks so much. Ill give you the bounty when I am able too.

Comment: You're welcome. The simpler mistakes are always the most difficult to track down !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `href` you are using in the template.  The Backbone Router is watching for changes to the `hash` portion of the site URL, which is the content after the `#` symbol.

So your href should be: `<a href="/#project/<%= id %>">` (notice the `#` before "project")

In that fashion, you won't even need a click handler at all, the Router will automatically capture the hash change event and route accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but that still does not fix the issue of the errors I am getting. If I am not mistaken, enabling pushstate should make it so that I don't have to have the hash. And someone can just go to ..../projects/someid and get the right information.

Answer (score 1):

Both [thibauts'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284951/656539) and [providencemac's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19124769/656539) assessments are right. Either don't use pushState and go with hash links or put a rewrite rule in your server to send the statics.

initially when you load you load this url -

```
http://localhost:8888
```

like wise url of your statics is along this

```
http://localhost:8888/js/backbone.js
```

the actually problem is when you use pushState and visit a link. Your browser url becomes. something like this -

```
http://localhost:8888/project/some_img_id
```

Now when you try to reload the page, the index file is taken from this url -

```
http://localhost:8888/project/your_default.file   [index.html]
```

Which your server fails to find and defaults to index file at

```
http://localhost:8888/your_default.file
```

And when the browser tries to access the statics it again defaults to index file

```
http://localhost:8888/project/js/backbone.js
```

thats why the error. as it finds '<' character which is invalid toekn in javascript.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < js/jquery.js:1
```

this error cause the file its trying to parse is backbone.js a javascript but its gets your index.html

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8888/project/js/backbone.js".
```

Comment: Thanks that explanation as well, it was very helpful! If I could split the bounty I would.

Comment: lol. no need. accept thibauts as he did spot the problem (why it wen wrong) you missed. providencemac's answer told another point (what went wrong). i simply put the two and said how it all went wrong.